# 9999 answers - Who is next to make it to a 10,000?

Tags: discussion

9999 answers! Who dares? This is a pretty milestone isn't it?! Up to a full site? Do the number of answers actually count as an absolute number?

Answer (score 6):

It is 10k now.

[image]

Also, [critical mass](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) I believe is more important to site graduation then number of questions. Here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta) more link. I would like to note that when I first joined visitors per day was about 5000 to 6000 so that is big gain.

> There is no set amount of time for a site to remain in beta; it will be in beta for as long as necessary to reach critical mass, with periodic evaluations that help communities know where they stand and what they need to work on.

Yes # of answer should be absolute; that is, if question X has 2 answers, it counts as two as opposed to one answer (the checked one) for the post.

It also may be worth while to note that good is 2.5 answers per post so we should be answering more questions to improve our standing in that category.

[image]

Comment: As of my point of view the "problem" with posting more answers to give alternatives is that most of the questions in Biology SE does not really have alternate answers, in contrast to for eg. StackOverflow where multiple solutions is plausible.

Comment: @poka.nandor a new answer doesn't just have to be another way to word the solution. In [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30928/does-taking-a-shower-have-the-same-effect-on-muscles-as-warming-up), I provided a new answer by focusing on one sepific topic in the question. We just have to be more creative when providing additional answers.

Comment: A good point, note taken. I'm always thinking in giving the fullest answer possible - thus I usually end up with a more general solution, but focusing on details when a general answer is given is also a good way to improve the site. I'll try to remember this.

Comment: Visits per day will increase when the semester starts :P